# Реализовать алгоритм для замены/расширения блока элементов, начиная с произвольного индекса массива. Ошибка на этапе выполнения

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, консоль

Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    srand(unsigned(time(0)));

        cout << "Реализовать алгоритм для вставки блока элементов, начиная с 
        произвольного индекса массива\n\n";
        cout << "Введите размер массива: ";
        int sizeA;
        cin >> sizeA;
        int *arrA = new int[sizeA];
        cout << "\nВаш массив: ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++)
        {
            arrA[x] = rand() % 9 + 1;
            cout << arrA[x] << " ";
        }

        cout << "\n\nВведите количество элементов которых будете добавлять/заменять в первом массиве: ";
        int amount;
        cin >> amount;

        cout << "\nВведите с какого элемента первого массива будете вставлять блок элементов (Считать с 0-го индекса): ";
        int change;
        cin >> change;

        int tmpsizeA = sizeA;
        if (change + amount > sizeA)
        {
            sizeA += amount - change - 1;
        }

        cout << "\nТеперь по очередности эти элементы (Ввод-пробел-ввод): ";
        for (int x = change; x < change + amount; x++)
        {
            cin >> arrA[x];
        }

        if (change + amount > sizeA)
        {
            sizeA = change + amount;
        }
        else
        {
            sizeA = tmpsizeA;
        }

        cout << "\nКонечный итог: ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++)
        {
            cout << arrA[x] << " ";
        }

        delete[] arrA;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Всё вроде бы работает, проверял при разных комбинациях несколько раз, но вот проблема одна. Если кол-во элементов которые я добавляю больше чем начальный размер массива то при нажатии на консоли enter вместо закрытия консоль издает звук виндовса и крашится. Но результат при этом верный. Мусорных значений нет.

Comment: Не понял. В чем именно состоит задача? Что значит "вставить"? Если в массив *вставить* блок элементов, то размер массива должен увеличиться на размер этого блока. Однако у вас в коде я нигде не вижу выделения памяти для нового - увеличенного - массива. Как это может работать? Также у вас в коде я вообще не вижу никаких попыток "вставки" элементов. Вместо вставки делается просто замена одних элементов на другие.

Comment: Пользователь выбирает с какого элемента массива начинать заменять элементы массива. Если выходит за грань массива то он расширяется и элементы добавляются к массиву, если нет то замена происходит внутри него же без расширения массива. Все операции с одним и тем же массивом.

Comment: Так почему вы тогда написали "вставить", если вам нужно "заменять"? "Заменить" и "вставить" - это совершенно разные вещи. "Расширяется и элементы добавляются", говорите? Ну и где у вас в коде *расширение* массива? Или вы ожидаете что он для вас магически сам по себе расширяться будет?

Comment: Не знаю как иначе, если знаете скажите. Мне просто интересно почему издает звук и где сопутствующая ошибка. Но также интересно было бы посмотреть на вашу реализацию данного задания. Заголовок исправил.

Comment: Ошибка - вылет за пределы массива, разумеется. Как я уже сказал выше, сам по себе он для вас "расширяться" не будет. Отсюда и "звук".

Comment: Если он не расширяется то почему когда я ввожу количество элементов больше чем может быть в массиве то эти элементы отображаются корректно не в виде мусорных значений?

Comment: А почему бы и нет? Это называется *неопределенное поведение*. Неопределенное поведение до поры до времени может выглядеть и так, как будто "все работает". Но это не более чем случайность.

Comment: Окей, а где исправить? Что добавить, что урезать?

Comment: Я уже написал: если вы хотите, чтобы ваш массив стал больше, вам нужно его самостоятельно ручками сделать больше. Выделить новую память правильного размера, перенести туда старые данные, добавить новые, освободить старую память и т.д.

Comment: почему нельзя просто увеличить size и заполнить его элементами? он же динамический

Comment: Слово "динамический" означает "располагающийся в динамической памяти", т.е. созданный через `new`. Ни больше, ни меньше. К размеру массива слово "динамический" никакого отношения не имеет. Менять свой размер этот массив для вас не будет. Массивы в С++ так не работают. Хотите поменять размер массива - придется менять его явно и самостоятельно. Именно путем создания нового массива и уничтожения старого. Все это намного проще реализовать через `std::vector`, но я подозреваю, что `std::vector` вам использовать "нельзя". Так?

Answer (score 0):

Ты увеличиваешь переменную sizeA неправильно первый раз. Но падает не из-за этого, а из-за того что ты не меняешь размер массива, в результате чего получаешь выход за пределы массива во время считывания измененных значений. Если хочешь работать с динамическим массивом лучше используй std::vector у него есть такие функции как size() и resize()

Comment: То, что Вы написали - это комментарий (причем по делу), но не ответ. Пока Вы не имеете права писать комментарии в силу невысокого рейтинга. Поэтому, есть смысл расширить Ваш комментарий до полноценного ответа, что увеличит Ваш рейтинг. В противном случае по правилам форума его снесут модераторы.